# node_modules folder size way to big

Tags: node.js, next.js, node-modules

I recently created a new next app just for checking the size of node_modules and it has a size of 320mb which it can increase. Is that a normal thing, or i have to be aware of something?

Does it have anything to do with the node version?

Comment: [That's pretty normal.](https://hackaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/node_modules-meme.png)

Comment: Really?. I though it was out of normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal thing in the NPM world. The reason why node_modules can get absurdly huge has to do with how the packages and their references are stored.

Let's say that you need package **A**, but the package **A** depends on packages **B** and **C**. Package **B** depends on packages **C**, **E**, and **F**.

The package **C** that you pulled with the needed package **A** also depends on packages **E**, **F**, and **G**.

Can you spot the trend here?
With the NPM, you may be pulling the same packages many (many) times.

> i have to be aware of something?

Yes, that is, only pull packages you **absolutely** need.

Answer (score 0):

That is completely normal. Am building a Next blog, and it is already at 437 MB. It's not usual for them to reach 1GB.

[image]